# datetime.combine() gets my Flask app and pc blocked

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-datetime

I am using Flask app to get info from all daily hours from SQLAlchemy

If SQLAlchemy query.all() doesn't return all hours of the day, because they doesn't exists in the target table, I use a for loop to insert the missing hours before return with jsonfy to the route.

I have a route like this

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import datetime as dt

@app.route("/getall")
def get_all():
    try:
        ttt = TruckTurnaroundTime.query.filter(TruckTurnaroundTime.hour != None).all()

        for i, o in enumerate(ttt):
            if i == 0:
                if o.hour != dt.time(0, 0):
                    ttt.insert(i, TruckTurnaroundTime(dt.time(0, 0), None))
                old_o = o
                continue

            current_hour = (dt.datetime.combine(dt.date(1, 1, 1), old_o.hour) + dt.timedelta(hours=1)).time()

            if o.hour != current_hour:
                ttt.insert(i, TruckTurnaroundTime(current_hour, None))

            old_o = o

        return jsonify([e.serialize() for e in ttt])
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

The problem is that when I go to the route (via browser) my computer just simply blocks and never loads the route "/getall"

If I get rid of this lines:

```
if o.hour != current_hour:
    ttt.insert(i, TruckTurnaroundTime(current_hour, None))
```

the problem dissapears.

I think the problem is something related with dt.datetime.combine() but I don't know.

This is my **models.py**:

```
from app import db


class TruckTurnaroundTime(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'truck_turnaround_time'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    hour = db.Column(db.Time())
    truck_turnaround_time = db.Column(db.Float)

    def __init__(self, hour, truck_turnaround_time):
        self.hour = hour
        self.truck_turnaround_time = truck_turnaround_time

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'hour': str(self.hour),
            'truck_turnaround_time': self.truck_turnaround_time
        }
```

EDIT: Python version 3.8.5

Comment: Try collecting the data for the inserts in a list and do the inserts once the loop has finished.

Comment: The line is exactly this: (if o.hour != current_hour:), if I perform greater comparison it works fine: (if o.hour > current_hour:)